# 2 Visas at the same time (D and C type)

Tags: visas, schengen-visas

I am currently an Erasmus student in Portugal. In my passport I have 2 visas one of them D type from Portugal and other one is schengen from Germany. I will stay in Portugal 6 months but my D type visa ends before my return. After my D type visa expires, is it possible for me to use my 90 days with the visa from Germany without leaving and coming back the EU zone?

Comment: No, you will have to leave Portugal and re-enter the Schengen zone.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But are you sure? Because i've found this statement on the internet.                                                             
                                                                                                      Periods of stay authorised under a residence permit or a long-stay visa shall not be taken into account in the calculation of the duration of stay on the territory of the Member States.

Comment: That is correct, but if you do not leave the country before your visa expires, you technically overstay.